# How to exit a process without any unwinding in C++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables, destructor, stack-unwinding

In C++11 or later, we can call `std::quick_exit` to exit a process without any unwinding, that is, no destructor will be called [after | during] `std::quick_exit`.

I have a project:

1. It has a global object, and there is a fatal bug in the destructor of the global object;
2. I have no access to the source of the global object;
3. If I can call `std::quick_exit` at the last line of `main` function, the bug won't be triggered;
4. For some reason, the project must be compiled with a C++98 compiler; that is to say, I cannot call `std::quick_exit` in a C++98 compiler.

In short:

**What function in C++98 is equivalent to C++11's `std::quick_exit`?**

Under Windows, I can call `ExitProcess(0)` to forcibly exit a process without any cleanup.

**What's the counterpart under Linux?**

Comment: Try `_exit()`. It's not clearly documented for pre-C++ 11 standard, but this should also bypass calling global destructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `abort()` from `<cstdlib>`. It sends a `SIGABRT` to a process and if the signal is not caught the program is terminated without calling any destruction routines like `atexit()` or any destructors.

More info here: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort)

Edit: `std::quick_exit` exits normally, whereas calling `abort()` results in abnormal termination, don't know if that's a problem.